# Alternative to adding the gem 'rails-controller-testing'

Tags: ruby, rspec, request, ruby-on-rails-6

I am trying to test that a template was rendered in a request test (via Rspec), but I prefer not to add the rails-controller-testing gem.  Is there another alternative?

```
expect(response).to render_template(:index) # add gem 'rails-controller-testing' to your Gemfile first.
```

Comment: Why do you not want to use the gem? It's designed to solve this exact problem, and it's [non-trivial](https://github.com/rails/rails-controller-testing/blob/a60b3da1c1c77959b28606dd087c058c64b5a08f/lib/rails/controller/testing/template_assertions.rb#L109-L192).

Comment: What I'd probably suggest though, is: Test *behaviour*, not *implementation*. Why is it important for the `index` template to be rendered? What significance does that have? Could you test something that checks for the significant behaviour, rather than testing this implementation detail? For example, maybe you could check that a certain HTML element is present in the rendered response body?

Comment: It was removed for a reason and I thought there was a better recommended solution or method for testing.

Comment: I thought about testing a specific element on the page, but  could see a situation were I look that it contains a word or phrase that is also on another page and it would pass when it should not.

Comment: It was removed because (to quote the rails core team) "controller tests should be more concerned about what is the result of that controller action like what cookies are set, or what HTTP code is set rather than testing of the internals of the controller". In other words, exactly like I suggested: It's generally considered better practice to test **behaviour**, not **implementation**. The question shouldn't be "how can i test the implementation, without using this gem that tests the implementation?"

Comment: Maybe it's not important at all to check that a specific partial is rendered, then? Maybe that was always a bit overkill? Maybe just checking that the response status is 200 is good enough? Or, maybe you could check some specific **element** like `#users-table` is rendered, instead of a really fuzzy match against a string. At the end of the day, this is your code and your tests; if you really feel it's beneficial to explicitly test which partial is rendered then I'd say to keep using the gem!

Comment: I am actually trying to test https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/blob/45b831c4ea5a35914037bd27fe88b76d7b3683a4/app/controllers/devise/confirmations_controller.rb#L30 , I modified the #show action and need to confirm it's working right

Comment: I can't reasonably pass any judgement on that, given I haven't seen how you've changed it, nor why, nor what it achieves. So I'll just repeat my previous opinion: If you really think that testing which template gets rendered is the best approach, then keep using the gem. But if you actually think this is unnecessary, or if there's a better way to test *behaviour* rather than *implementation*, then write your test differently. Either way, the premise of "implementing a test in this way, but without using the gem" seems pointless to me.

Comment: Thank you, much appreciated